# DataBase Testing By using Autowire in Integration Testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, integration-testing, autowired

I am new to DataBase testing and I am trying to Connect the database by using tag @SpringBootTest in class level and by using Autowire, It is not creating instantiation getting always null

```java
@SprintBootTest
 Class  Test{
@Autowire
     DatabaseService databaseService;

}
```

Can anyone suggest please? If any one did similar like this , can you please give me the instructions

Comment: We need more information about how your application is set up and which packages the involved classes/interfaces are: the test, the application the `DatabaseService` and if separate it's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to test your database and here is a couple of them,

**Using In-memory-database(ex: [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS))) using [`test`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) scope**

It's quite good to use h2(in-memory-DB) for mimicking the database. Though it is not mandatory and we can use [mockito](https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/junit-mockito-example/) to mock the database interactions as well.

Add these dependencies,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.196</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now your test class should look like this,

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = YourApp.class, webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
Class  DatabaseServiceTest{

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseService databaseService;
}
```

**Replicating actual database configuration properties**

First, you need to replicate your properties/yml from `main/resources` to `test/resources` directory. Your test class remains the same as given in the above approach. But make sure that you excluded the `h2-dependency` from your pom.

**Please explore these tutorials as well**,

- [spring integration testing](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-integration-testing/)
- [spring boot test](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing)
- [junit and mockito example](https://howtodoinjava.com/mockito/junit-mockito-example/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I copied properties from main/resources to test/resources but after I am getting failed to load application.

Comment: Without seeing *error trace* - would be *HARD* to suggest you, as there might be multiple reasons for that! Please consider putting your error trace.